# Dynamic SQLite Query db.Table<DYNAMIC> C#/UWP

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, dynamic

I should a DB Handler class develop. I want a method like dynamic `Select`, `Update`, `Delete`...

This is my code;

```
   using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(this.dbPath))
        {
            lst = db.Table<tabCOProzessRow>()).ToList();
        }
```

But I wanna like this; (with where condition)

```
  using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(this.dbPath))
        {
            lst = db.Table<***DYNAMIC***>()).ToList();
        }
```

Is it possible?

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could make a dynamic query with this code;

```
    public List<object> getTable(string TableName)
    {
        object[] obj = new object[] { };
        TableMapping map = new TableMapping(Type.GetType(TableName));
        string query = "select * from " + TableName;
        return db.Query(map, "query", obj).ToList();
    }
```

We can be more dynamically with buildQuery method.